# Problema con PHP discriminar par o impar

Tags: php, array

Estoy con un `array` con los 100 primeros números naturales. Quiero discriminar para cada número si se trata de par o impar pero me salta un error y no entiendo el porque. Creo un `array` vació luego le hago el `push` de los 100 números pero luego no discrimino bien. Saludos y gracias.

```
$array14 = array();
$numero14 = 101;
for ($i=1; $i < $numero14 ; $i++) { 
    array_push($array14, $i);
    if ($array14[$i]%2==0) {
        echo "Numero par";
    }
    else {
        echo "Numero impar";
    }   
}
```

Comment: Te dejo una respuesta, pero no termino de entender ¿para qué sirve el array vacío?, es decir ¿con qué lo vas a llenar?

Comment: Lo he de llenar con los numeros naturales

Comment: @PasioTech he añadido la solución a su pregunta, pero para mejorar la comprensión de la pregunta , futuras preguntas y ayude a más participantes, siempre es mejor añadir el mensaje de error o exception que le muestra su código y poder dar una mejor respuesta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error es por el indice, el primer elemento se inserta con [array_push()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-push.php) en la posición `0` del `array` pero luego intenta acceder al indice `1` que que es el valor por el cuál inicia el `for` para hacer la validación *(para o impar)* y no encuentra dicho indice.  `if ($array14[$i]%2==0)`

la solución es iniciar el `for` en 0

```
for ($i=0; $i < $numero14 ; $i++) { .. }
```

Comment: Mersi joel justo ahora runea bien. Ahora faltaria que lo perfeccionase poniendo el numero al lado de si es par o impar pq sino queda cutre pero ahora funciona y es de dar el tick de respuesta a utd :D

Answer (score 1):

Según leo la idea es que entre 1 y 101 que es el valor asignado a la variable `$numero14` es encontrar cuales números son pares y cuales son impares.

Entonces yo no noto mayor utilidad de `array_push($array14, $i);`

Entonces tu código debería ser así:

```
<?php

$numero14 = 101;

for($i=1; $i<$numero14; $i++){
    if($i %2 == 0){
        echo "par".PHP_EOL;
    }else{
        echo "impar".PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

- Dentro del `if` comparas el valor que por cada vuelta o iteración te devuelve la variable `$i` identificando si con el operador de módulo, el residuo es 0

El resultado debería ser similar a esto:

```
impar par impar par impar par impar par impar par impar par impar par impar par 
impar par impar par impar par impar par impar par impar par impar par impar par 
impar par impar par impar par impar par impar par impar par impar par impar par 
impar par impar par impar par impar par impar par impar par impar par impar par 
impar par impar par impar par impar par impar par impar par impar par impar par 
impar par impar par impar par impar par impar par impar par impar par impar par 
impar par impar par
```

Comment: Osea en el array almacenar los numeros naturales lo tengo que hacer asi.